# SQL 2005 Database not accessible

Tags: database, sql-server-2005

I've moved a database from sql 2000 to a new 2005 server.  Everything was fine until I logged into Sql Server Management studio with one particular user.  It looks like i logged in successfully but when I try to expand the database I get 'The database is not accessible'.  I can log in with windows authentication and with other sql users with no problem and can see everything.

I checked and made sure the DB is not in single user mode.  I also checked for orphaned logins (exec sp_change_users_login 'report') and none were found.

Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Voted to close (belongs on serverfault.com).

Answer (score 1):

check if the user has proper permissions to access the db.